# Convert keycode to character using javascript,like keyCode 27 to esc

Tags: javascript, variables, keycode

```
var key_code = 65;
```

and the result should be

```
character = "Esc";
```

I want to convert all the keys on the keyboard.
My demo is here:

```js
window.onload = function ()
{
 var oP = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0]; 
 document.onkeydown = function (event)
 {
  var event = event || window.event;
  oP.innerHTML = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
  return false
 }
}
```

```html
<p></p>
```

Comment: I think you might have to create an array of keys and match that up with the key pressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you'd have to create a object to store them and search for the one you want.

you'd need a collection such as

```
var keys = {
    "8" : "backspace",
    "9" : "tab"
}; 
keys["8"];//etc
```

N.B. You can't have numerical keys in json, only strings.

This would allow you to search for the keycode using the text name of the key.

If you are wanting to search for the key from the keycode, you'd use an array such as:

```
var keys = [0];
...
keys[8] = "backspace"; // etc
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,just wanna a convenient solution.

Comment: A little question...It should be  var keys = {
   8:"backspace",
   9:"tab"
};

Comment: No, you can't have numbers as keys in json, only strings

Answer (score 1):

//here's my final answer...hope to get any good advice,ths

```js
window.onload = function () {
        var showCode = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
        var keyMap = {
            "8":"BackSpace BackSpace",
            "9":"Tab Tab",
            "12":"Clear",
            "13":"Enter",
            "16":"Shift_L",
            "17":"Control_L",
            "18":"Alt_L",
            "19":"Pause",
            "20":"Caps_Lock",
            "27":"Escape Escape",
            "32":"space space",
            "33":"Prior",
            "34":"Next",
            "35":"End",
            "36":"Home",
            "37":"Left",
            "38":"Up",
            "39":"Right",
            "40":"Down",
            "41":"Select",
            "42":"Print",
            "43":"Execute",
            "45":"Insert",
            "46":"Delete",
            "47":"Help",
            "48":"0 equal braceright",
            "49":"1 exclam onesuperior",
            "50":"2 quotedbl twosuperior",
            "51":"3 section threesuperior",
            "52":"4 dollar",
            "53":"5 percent",
            "54":"6 ampersand",
            "55":"7 slash braceleft",
            "56":"8 parenleft bracketleft",
            "57":"9 parenright bracketright",
            "65":"a A",
            "66":"b B",
            "67":"c C",
            "68":"d D",
            "69":"e E EuroSign",
            "70":"f F",
            "71":"g G",
            "72":"h H",
            "73":"i I",
            "74":"j J",
            "75":"k K",
            "76":"l L",
            "77":"m M mu",
            "78":"n N",
            "79":"o O",
            "80":"p P",
            "81":"q Q at",
            "82":"r R",
            "83":"s S",
            "84":"t T",
            "85":"u U",
            "86":"v V",
            "87":"w W",
            "88":"x X",
            "89":"y Y",
            "90":"z Z",
            "96":"KP_0 KP_0",
            "97":"KP_1 KP_1",
            "98":"KP_2 KP_2",
            "99":"KP_3 KP_3",
            "100":"KP_4 KP_4",
            "101":"KP_5 KP_5",
            "102":"KP_6 KP_6",
            "103":"KP_7 KP_7",
            "104":"KP_8 KP_8",
            "105":"KP_9 KP_9",
            "106":"KP_Multiply KP_Multiply",
            "107":"KP_Add KP_Add",
            "108":"KP_Separator KP_Separator",
            "109":"KP_Subtract KP_Subtract",
            "110":"KP_Decimal KP_Decimal",
            "111":"KP_Divide KP_Divide",
            "112":"F1",
            "113":"F2",
            "114":"F3",
            "115":"F4",
            "116":"F5",
            "117":"F6",
            "118":"F7",
            "119":"F8",
            "120":"F9",
            "121":"F10",
            "122":"F11",
            "123":"F12",
            "124":"F13",
            "125":"F14",
            "126":"F15",
            "127":"F16",
            "128":"F17",
            "129":"F18",
            "130":"F19",
            "131":"F20",
            "132":"F21",
            "133":"F22",
            "134":"F23",
            "135":"F24",
            "136":"Num_Lock",
            "137":"Scroll_Lock",
            "187":"acute grave",
            "188":"comma semicolon",
            "189":"minus underscore",
            "190":"period colon",
            "192":"numbersign apostrophe",
            "210":"plusminus hyphen macron",
            "211":"",
            "212":"copyright registered",
            "213":"guillemotleft guillemotright",
            "214":"masculine ordfeminine",
            "215":"ae AE",
            "216":"cent yen",
            "217":"questiondown exclamdown",
            "218":"onequarter onehalf threequarters",
            "220":"less greater bar",
            "221":"plus asterisk asciitilde",
            "227":"multiply division",
            "228":"acircumflex Acircumflex",
            "229":"ecircumflex Ecircumflex",
            "230":"icircumflex Icircumflex",
            "231":"ocircumflex Ocircumflex",
            "232":"ucircumflex Ucircumflex",
            "233":"ntilde Ntilde",
            "234":"yacute Yacute",
            "235":"oslash Ooblique",
            "236":"aring Aring",
            "237":"ccedilla Ccedilla",
            "238":"thorn THORN",
            "239":"eth ETH",
            "240":"diaeresis cedilla currency",
            "241":"agrave Agrave atilde Atilde",
            "242":"egrave Egrave",
            "243":"igrave Igrave",
            "244":"ograve Ograve otilde Otilde",
            "245":"ugrave Ugrave",
            "246":"adiaeresis Adiaeresis",
            "247":"ediaeresis Ediaeresis",
            "248":"idiaeresis Idiaeresis",
            "249":"odiaeresis Odiaeresis",
            "250":"udiaeresis Udiaeresis",
            "251":"ssharp question backslash",
            "252":"asciicircum degree",
            "253":"3 sterling",
            "254":"Mode_switch"
        };
        document.onkeydown = function (event) {
            var event = event || window.event;
            var oKeyNumber = event.keyCode;
            showCode.innerHTML = keyMap[event.keyCode];
        }
    }
```

```css
p{text-align:center;font-size:6em;}
```

```html
<p></p>
```